# Add some easing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add some easing but it's not working :/

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300)
    {
        $(".userbar").animate({top:"0px"}, {duration: 100}, {easing:  easeInOutQuint});
    } 
    else
    {     
        $(".userbar").animate({top:"-70px"}, {duration: 100}, {easing: easeInOutQuint});
    }
});
```

How is it possible?

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8JYWf/)

Comment: The variable easeInOutQuint is never defined!

Comment: yeah, but you'll have to put quotes around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working fiddle here, your curly brackets were off as well as the quoting.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8JYWf/5/)

```
$(".userbar").animate({left:"0px"},{duration: 100,easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
```

Comment: no sry this easing is not working... http://jsfiddle.net/8JYWf/7/ ... I've implemented a special bouncing easing... its not working..

Comment: @andre34 That's because the duration is too fast for the eye to see the animation check this fiddle out with a duration of 1000 http://jsfiddle.net/8JYWf/8/